# SQL Server 2008 : find out which stored procedures writes to certain table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert, sql-update

I am trying to hunt down a certain stored procedure which writes to certain table (it needs to be changed) however going through every single stored procedure is not a route I really want to take. So I was hoping there might be a way to find out which stored procedures `INSERT` or `UPDATE` certain table.

I have tried using this method ([pinal_daves_blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/10/sql-server-find-stored-procedure-related-to-table-in-database-search-in-all-stored-procedure/)), but it is not giving me any results.

NOTICE: The stored procedure might not be in the same DB!

Is there another way or can I somehow check what procedure/function has made the last insert or update to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a trace in Profiler. The procedure would have to write to the table while the trace is running for you to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

One brute-force method would be to download an add-in from RedGate called SQL Search (free), then do a stored procedure search for the table name.  I'm not affiliated at all with RedGate or anything, this is just a method that I have used to find similar things and has served me well.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

If you go this route, you just type in the table name, change the 'object types' ddl selection to 'Procedures' and select 'All databases' in the DB ddl.

Hope this helps!  I know it isn't the most technical solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to tell what function, procedure, or executed batch has made the last change to a table.  There just isn't.  Some databases have this as part of their transaction logging but SQL Server isn't one of them.

I have wondered in the past whether transactional replication might provide that information, if you already have that set up, but I don't know whether that's true.

If you know the change has to be taking place in a stored procedure (as opposed to someone using SSMS or executing lines of SQL via ADO.NET), then @koppinjo's suggestion is a good one, as is this one from Pinal Dave's [blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/10/sql-server-2005-2000-search-string-in-stored-procedure/?relatedposts_hit=1&relatedposts_origin=10&relatedposts_position=0):

```
 USE AdventureWorks
 GO
 --Searching for Empoloyee table
 SELECT Name
 FROM sys.procedures
 WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%Employee%'
```

There are also dependency functions, though they can be outdated or incomplete:

```
select * from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities( 'dbo.Employee', 'object' )
```